# What is the most accurate experimental confirmation of Rutherford's $\sin^{-4}\frac{\phi}{2}$ law?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, scattering, atoms

What is the most accurate experimental confirmation to date of [Rutherford's $\sin^{-4}\frac{\phi}{2}$ law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering), where $\phi$ is the scattering angle?

Comment: What do you mean by precise? What parameter are you wondering about?

Comment: Arguably (if you are willing to allow electron scatter as being the same) G-zero or Q-weak, or something else that has happened at JLAB in the last ten years or so. But the question is not well formed. What metric do you want people to use for "precise". There are whole fields of nuclear and nucleon physics, and every experiment that happens in those fields is a scattering experiment.

Comment: I'd be willing to nominate this for reopening if you were to add a quantifier as to what *precise* means.

Comment: I do not have a recent reference to point you to.  The problem is that the Rutherford cross section as derived is the direct result of an inverse square scattering potential (yes, it can be applied to gravitational scattering as well as electrostatics).  Any measure deviations from pure Rutherford are then the basis of nuclear physics experiments probing the structure of the nucleus (or other particles), that is the inverse square assumptions have broken down and something else has come in to play (nuclear physics).

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, that's true. Perhaps what I'm looking for is the most recent Rutherford experiment performed exactly as Rutherford's but with more precise equipment

Comment: One place to start is N.P. Barradas et al., Nucl. Instrum. Methods B316 81-87 (2013).  It is about measurements of the scattering cross sections of protons off of C-13, and has a number of references to the most current cross-section databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](http://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.21.1891)* seems to be one of the most recent papers that concerns itself with the OP's equation directly. Anything since then appears to take it as fact and use it to determine something else.

*Large-angle scattering of light ions in the weakly screened Rutherford region.
Phys. Rev. A 21, 1891 – Published 1 June 1980 -
H. H. Andersen, F. Besenbacher, P. Loftager, and W. Möller